# setting a variable to be used in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function like this:

```
var name_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,32}$/,
body_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]$/,
email_regex = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/,
phone_regex = /^[0-9-]{3,32}$/,
error_count;

function validation_test (name, value) {
    var test_name = name + '_regex';
    console.log(test_name);
    error_count = 0;
    if(!test_name.test(value)){
        error_count += 1;
    }
}
```

And if I try to run it (on submit) I get following error:

**test_name.test is not a function**

console.log(test_name) is giving me the proper name for the variable (for example name_regex). How can I make this variable work?

Comment: So `test_name` contains the name of a function you want to run?

Comment: You could try `window[test_name]` if it is defined in the global scope. Else `namespace[test_name]` where `namespace` is the namespace where the variable to test are defined in.

Comment: `test` is one of the methods of regular expression object, not the string.

Comment: Added the rest of the code to be clear what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an object:

```
var regexes = {
    name: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,32}$/,
    body: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]$/,
    email: /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/,
    phone: /^[0-9-]{3,32}$/
};



function isValid(name, value) {
    return regexes[name].test(value);
}
```

In your other code:

```
   if( !isValid( "phone", 123 ) ) {
       alert("Invalid phone");
   }
```

Comment: Well he could simply use `window[test_name]` if he wants to.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to accomplish the same task in Javascript, yes. I would never recommend the above one.

Comment: @Sasha you are resetting `error_count` to `0` every time `validation_test` is called, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, because if there is there is an error, error_count will be 1, but if all goes well error_count will be 0 (there is JQuery each function which checks each required field). Is this good method to do, or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: @Sasha well it's very confusing because the whole `error_count` is useless then. You might as well return `true` or `false` because you are not keeping any count, the result is always either `0` or `1` which is better expressed by `false` and `true`

Comment: Hmmm, my newbe JS mind never considerate this. So basically I return false, and if there is any false result, I can do magic :D ?

Comment: @Sasha I have edited the code to show it.. basically `.test` already returns either `true` or `false` so there is no need for manual `return true` or `return false` either

Comment: Nice one :). I find your help quite educational for me, and for that I thank you :).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19783/discussion-between-sasha-and-esailija)

Answer (score 1):

variable test_name should be proper regExp object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

consider

```
...
function validation_test (name, value) {
    var test_name = name + '_regex';
    console.log(typeof(test_name)); // string
...
```

Than happen because of concatenation on the line above console log

Comment: you are welcome, and I guess correct answer would be because you pass string name as well. So probably string conversion is another option did not really looked details on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression but looks like constructive

Comment: oh sorry, that's not case, it is just another thing:)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to call the function e.g.

```
validation_test('phone', '9184079201');
```

If so, I'd recommend putting your regular expressions into an object:

```
var regex = {
    'name':  '...',
    'body':  '...',
    'email': '...',
    'phone': '...',
};

function validation_test(name, value) {
    if(!regex[name].test(value)) {
        //...
    }
}
```

That way you can look them up by string.

Comment: This method is also working, but Esailija was first to give an answer, so I can only give you an upvote :(. Nevertheless, thank you for your help. There is nothing wrong with more knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

`test_name` is a string, not the regex it represents, so `!test_name.test(value)` won't do what you want.

Since you're not using `name` anywhere else in the function, why don't you just pass the regex in as an argument?

```
function validation_test (test_name, value) {
    error_count = 0;
    if(!test_name.test(value)){
        error_count += 1;
    }
}
```