# Convert a string into a regular expression

Tags: javascript, string, textinput

I am using a very fine JavaScript library called ["array-query"](https://github.com/jacwright/array-query/blob/master/lib/query.js) by Jacob Wright to do searches in arrays of objects.

One method is `regex()` where a regular expression can be included in parentheses like this: `regex(/[^\w\s]/)`. If I hardcode the expression as I just showed it works fine. If I put the same expression in a variable first it does not work, like this:

```
var reg = "/[^\w\s]/"; 
regex(reg);
```

I was told

> You are putting quotes around your regex, making it a string. Remove the quotes.

Thus

```
var reg = /[^\w\s]/; 
regex(reg);
```

works fine.

Problem is I need to accept the user input from an textbox as part of the regular expression. For example if the user types in the letter `z` it needs to get changed to `/z/`. Even if I type in `/z/` the `textbox.value` returned has the same problem as a `var reg = "/z/"`. If I hardcode `var reg = /z/; regex(reg);` it works fine.

How to make a input textbox value of `"z"` into a form that is `var reg = z;`?
Many many thanks for any help or ideas, hope this isn't too confusing.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression

Comment: This as been asked before, have a look at the link mzedeler posted. I also recommend to read some documentation about regular expressions in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Answer (score 4):

You should do

```
var regex = new RegExp('your regex string');
```

Basically you can think of

```
var regex = /pattern/modifiers;
```

as

```
var regex = new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);
```

Read more about it at: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) or [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 2):

```
var reg = new RegExp("string");
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do something like this:

```
var string = $('#input_id').val();
string = string.replace('/', '');

var regexpPattern = '/'+string+'/';
regex(regexpPattern);
```

Comment: `regex` expects a RegExp object, not a string.

Comment: That's very wrong. `"/foo/"` is a string, while `/foo/` is a regex literal. The OP even mentioned that in the question, have you read it?

Comment: I haven't include any double quotes. I have just concatinate the slashes with the text that are captured via input box. Have you read my code carefully?

Comment: you can change it to RegExp object like: var reg = new RegExp('/'+string+'/');

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use single or double quotes. Both denote a string. I could also have written `'/foo/'` if you like that better. Yes, passing the value to `RegExp` is necessary here and that's the actual solution! **But** including the slashes is wrong. The correct solution would be `regex(new RegExp(string))`. Otherwise the regex would only match if the value literally contains `/`.

Comment: Wow!! Thank you all sooooo much for such fast and great answers. It works!!! var reg = new RegExp(string); I can breath again. Markandeya

Comment: @skparwal maybe you wanted to write something like this `var _str = "sample string";  _str = "/"+_str+"/s";  var _reg = new RegExp (_str); `