# How to convert string-encoded PHP regex to JS regex on the fly?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string

I have a very simple regex that I am using for highlighting search terms in my application.  If a user types in 'stack' into the search form, for example, the following regular expression is used as a string argument for `preg_match_all` to highlight the results:

```
"/\b((stack|stacks))\b/i"
```

I am using `json_encode` to output some of my configuration options for my application, including the regex above.  I need this regex on the client-side because I am lazy-loading pagination items in an infinite-scroll fashion, and I want to take advantage of the client-side to parse the HTML for the proper search term highlighting.

My JS configuration object now appears similar to:

```
config = {
   searchRegex: "/\b((stack|stacks))\b/i",
   // ... more options
}
```

If `searchRegex` wasn't a string, I wouldn't have a problem.  It would automatically be a regular expression object, and there is nothing in that regex that JavaScript doesn't support.  But now, I have to resort to parsing the string to get the appropriate arguments for the `RegExp` constructor, which involves removing the delimiters and getting the modifier(s).  With all the escaped characters that could be present, this doesn't seem like a viable or sane option.

How would I convert `searchRegex` to become a regular expression object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression. It does not give another solution than using the RegExp constructor, but I think there isn't.

Comment: Why not simplifying your reg-ex with `/\b(stacks?)\b/i`, which would then be mutated into `/\\b(stacks?)\\b/i` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.  I decided to output the regex-based string sans modifiers and delimiters to the client and use JS to pass it and the separated modifier to the `RegExp` constructor.  Ended up with something similar to:

```
config = {
    searchRegex: '\b((stack|stacks))\b',
    modifiers: 'i'
}

// ... later
model.initialize = function () {
    config.searchRegex = new RegExp(config.searchRegex, config.modifiers || '');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A really **hacky** way to do this is to eval it. If you can trust the inputs, it might be an okay solution.

```
function evalRegExp(str) {
  return eval(str);
}

var re = evalRegExp("/foo/i");
// => /foo/i
```

If you use this a lot, it might be okay to add this as a method directly to `RegExp`

```
RegExp.eval = function(str) {
  return eval(str);
};

var re = RegExp.eval("/foo/i");
// => /foo/i
```

Comment: shouldnt we use RegExp.prototype.evalRegExp = function() {} ;

Comment: @PsychHalf hmm no. If the function is put on the prototype, it means we need an instance of RegExp in order to call that function. Putting the function directly on `RegExp` makes it sort of like a factory that actually returns a new instance of `RegExp`.

Comment: Never thought of this, thanks.  I tend to refrain from `eval` (and rightfully so) but I forgot that it would be that simple if I did use it.

Comment: @danronmoon, right, `eval` is generally an ill-advised thing to use, but in this particular case, if you trust the inputs, it's probably fine.

Comment: @maček you are right.. the code runs fine but in my debugger i got.. Line 1: RegExp.eval = function(str) { --- Expected an identifier and instead saw 'eval' (a reserved word). Line 1: RegExp.eval = function(str) { --- eval is evil.
Line 2: return eval(str); --- eval is evil. so i was just asking..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best parse but i've got it working parsed as an array `[regexp, modifiers]` ready to create a new instance of `RegExp`. Hope it helps...

`'/some[a-z]+regex/i'.replace(/^(.)(.+)\1([gim])+/, function (foo, bar, regexp, modifiers) { return [regexp, modifiers].join('___') }).split('___')`

Comment: I think you'd have trouble with escaped delimiters here. Such as `/foo\/bar/i`. Not to mention, if the input string had `___` in it, it would also fail.

Comment: @maček yeah, you're right :( I regret about the entire "solution" right now... just nevermind.

Answer (score -5):

Use `unescape()`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

```
var str="Need tips? Visit W3Schools!";
var str_esc=escape(str);
document.write(str_esc + "<br>")
document.write(unescape(str_esc))
```

Comment: This will not help at all.

Comment: Nothing related to the question

Comment: he wants to unescape the string?