# Dynamic insertion is not working in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function

```
function validateUsername(str,minL,maxL){// i'm passing validateUsername("asdf_1",2,8)
var exp=new RegExp(/^[a-z0-9_-]\w{"+minL+","+maxL+"}$/);
switch(exp.test(str)){
    case true: return true;
    case false: return false;
  }
}
```

I want to insert minimum Length and maximum length dynamically,
But if above code used,its giving me false whether it should accept the string as true.

can anyone tell me, what should i use rather "+variable+" to insert the value dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @k102- dude, i asked, what should i use so that i will get my answer true, in return case.
this function is using for password validation. i know its little same question, but my problem is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [regex object constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to build your regex from a string as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874722/1665540).

Example taken from linked answer :

```
var re = new RegExp("a|b", "i");
// same as
var re = /a|b/i;
```

In your case that would do something like :

```
function validateUsername(str,minL,maxL){// i'm passing validateUsername("asdf_1",2,8)
  var exp=new RegExp("^[a-z0-9_-]\w{" + minL + "," + maxL + "}$");
  /*
  why ???
  switch(exp.test(str)){
    case true: return true;
    case false: return false;
  }
  */
  return exp.test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate length validation from the pattern, something like this

```
if(str.length<minL || str.length>maxL){
// invalid length
}else{
var exp=new RegExp(/^[a-z0-9_-]\w$/);
 return exp.test(str)
}
```

Comment: This will cause result false, {required,required} in my case, otherwise false output.

Comment: i am not checking length, i want to insert dynamic minimum and maximum  length inside my regEx.