# How can we split a string using starts with regular expression (/^myString/g)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, split

I am having a case where i need to split given string using starts with regex **(/^'searchString'/)** which is not working such as

```
"token=123412acascasdaASDFADS".split('token=')
```

Here i want to extract the token value but as there might be some other possible parameters such as 
   `"reset_token=SDFDFdsf12313ADADF".split('token=')`

Here it also split the string with 'token=', Thats why i need to split the string using some regex which states that split the string where it starts with given string.

Thanks..

**EDITED**
Guys thanks for your valuable response this issue can be resolve using **/\btoken=/** BUT BUT its does not work if 'token=' stored as a string into a variable such as

```
sParam = 'token=';
"token=123412acascasdaASDFADS".split(/\bsParam/);
```

This does not works.

Comment: do you have only one token or more?

Comment: Is there a parameter separator like `&` between each `param=value` group?

Comment: there will unique parameters with different names such as token=dfd&refresh_token=dfdsf. So split does work on getting exact token= value.

Comment: You should first split the whole parameter string using `&`, then loop through that testing whether it begins with `token=`.

Comment: I am already doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex in split with word boundary:

```
"token=123412acascasdaASDFADS".split(/\btoken=/)
```

If `token` is stored in a variable then use `RegExp` constructor:

```
var sParam = "token";
var re = new RegExp("\\b" + sParam + "=");
```

Then use it:

```
var tokens = "token=123412acascasdaASDFADS".split( re );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 'token=' is stored as a string into a variable name as sParam, now if i try "token=123412acascasdaASDFADS".split(/\bsParam/) than it does not work.

Comment: check my updated answer for using it from a variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the use case for the `\b` anchor:

```
\btoken=
```

It ensures there's no other *word* character before `token` (a word character being `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `String#match()` function and get the matched group from index 1

sample code

```
var re = /^token=(.*)$/; 
var str = 'token=123412acascasdaASDFADS';


console.log('token=123412acascasdaASDFADS'.match('/^token=(.*)$/')[1]);
```

output:

```
123412acascasdaASDFADS
```

---

If `token` is dynamic then use **`RegExp`**

```
var token='token=';
var re = new RegExp("^"+token+"(.*)$");

var str = 'token=123412acascasdaASDFADS';

console.log(str.match(re)[1]);
```

[Learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string using the `&` parameter delimiter, then loop through those parameters:

```
var token;
$.each(params.split('&'), function() {
    var parval = this.split('=');
    if (parval[0] == "token") {
        token = parval[1];
        return false; // end the $.each loop
    }
});
```

if you just use `token=` as the `split` delimiter, you'll include all the other parameters after it in the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you need, but this may be an idea to work with?

```
var reqstr = "token=12345&reset_token=SDFDFdsf12313ADADF&someval=foo"
              .split(/[&=]/)
   ,req = [];
reqstr.map( function (v, i) {
             if (i%2==0) {
              var o = {}; 
              o[/token/i.test(v) ? 'token' : v] = reqstr[i+1]; 
              this.push(o);
             } return v
            }, req);
 /* => req now contains:
     [ { token: '12345' },
       { token: 'SDFDFdsf12313ADADF' },
       { someval: 'foo' } ]
 */
```