# How to check part of string matches array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this

```
var invalidChars = ["^", "_", "[", "]"];

var inputText = "abc^"   - true
var inputText = "abc_"   - true
var inputText = "abc"    - false
```

Can any one please let me know how can I check if my input string contains any items in array using jQuery/Javascript?

I tried $.InArray and indexof . its not working as those check for whole string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **[`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** and **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**

> some() executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, some() immediately returns true. Otherwise, some() returns false. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values. ( Taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) )

```js
var invalidChars = ["^", "_", "[", "]"];

var inputText = "abc^";
var inputText1 = "abc_";
var inputText2 = "abc";

console.log(
  invalidChars.some(function(v) {
    return inputText.indexOf(v) != -1;
  }),
  invalidChars.some(function(v) {
    return inputText1.indexOf(v) != -1;
  }),
  invalidChars.some(function(v) {
    return inputText2.indexOf(v) != -1;
  })
)
```

---

For old browser check [polyfill option for method some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill).

---

Also you can use regex to achieve the result. Generate the regex using the array and check for match in string.

```js
var invalidChars = ["^", "_", "[", "]"];

var inputText = "abc^";
var inputText1 = "abc_";
var inputText2 = "abc";

var regex = new RegExp(invalidChars.map(function(v) {
  return v.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&');
}).join('|'));

console.log(
  regex.test(inputText),
  regex.test(inputText1),
  regex.test(inputText2)
)
```

Refer this answer for string to regex conversion : [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using regex pattern and `RegExp.test` method:

```
var re = /[\^\[\]_]/;

console.log(re.test("abc^"));  // true
console.log(re.test("abc_"));  // true
console.log(re.test("abc"));   // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your asked about jquery:

```
var contains, inputText;
var invalidChars = ["^", "_", "[", "]"];

inputText = "abc^"   // true
contains = $(invalidChars).filter(inputText.split('')).length > 0; // true

inputText = "abc_"   // true
contains = $(invalidChars).filter(inputText.split('')).length > 0; // true

inputText = "abc"    // false
contains = $(invalidChars).filter(inputText.split('')).length > 0; // false
```