# How to remove string between two words in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

How to remove string between two words in javascript.

```
var myString="?specs=f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_test%3a2+GB!!2!!||f_test%3a4+GB!!3!!||f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_demo%3a16+GB!!5!!||||Category:Notebooks"
```

I want to remove all word start with "f_test" and end with "||".

output string like :

```
?specs=f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_demo%3a16+GB!!5!!||||Category:Notebooks"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What've you attempted or tried?

Comment: Where is code what you have tried to remove the desired string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method with regex **[`/f_test[^|]+\|\|/g`](https://regex101.com/r/rJ3sX7/2)**(or **[`/f_test.+?\|\|/g`](https://regex101.com/r/oP9lI6/2)**)

```js
var myString = "?specs=f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_test%3a2+GB!!2!!||f_test%3a4+GB!!3!!||f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_demo%3a16+GB!!5!!||||Category:Notebooks";

console.log(
  myString.replace(/f_test[^|]+\|\|/g, '')
)
```

**UPDATE :** If `test` is loading from a string variable then generate regex using **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** constructor.

```js
var k = "test",
  myString = "?specs=f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_test%3a2+GB!!2!!||f_test%3a4+GB!!3!!||f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_demo%3a16+GB!!5!!||||Category:Notebooks";

console.log(
  myString.replace(RegExp('f_' + k + '[^|]+\\|\\|', 'g'), '')
)
```

Refer : [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)

Comment: If i want like this then 
var myString = "?specs=f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_test%3a2+GB!!2!!||f_test%3a4+GB!!3!!||f_demo%3a8+GB!!4!!||f_demo%3a16+GB!!5!!||||Category:Notebooks";
var k="test";
myString=  myString.replace(/f_@k[^|]+\|\|/g, '')

What about k?

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara :  glad to help... :)