# How to get count of matches in a string by using Preg_match in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to replace the tags with its available value.

But in a string may have multiple of same tags.

So i need to fetch and replace,

**Array Sample** :

```
 var result = {
     '[name]':'user_name',
     '[age]':29
 };
```

**String** :

```
<p id="text">
Hi [name], I really want to thank you. 
You([name]), really done a great job.

user,
 [name]-[age]
</p>
```

**Javascript** :

```
  var text = document.getElementByID('text');
  text.replace(string, value); // this replacement only helps first hit.
```

Here, i use "[name]" for 3 times, i have replacement value.

But i cant use ".replace()" function, because it wont work on second tag (if same).

Is it Possible ?

Or Any other Solution to Solve this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `replace()` only replaces the first occurence. Use a RexExp instead.

Comment: yes it is possible to replace all tags. This similar to templates resolution in general. you can use any template engine like handlebar, underscore template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate regex from the string and replace with property value. where yo can use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to generate the regex from the string.

```js
var result = {
  '[name]': 'user_name',
  '[age]': 29
};

var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
res = text.replace(
  // generate regex
  new RegExp(
    // get all keys from object
    Object.keys(result)
    // iterate and escape symbols which have special meaning in regex
    .map(function(v) {
      return v.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&');
    })
    // join using pipe symbol and set global modifier
    // for replacing all occurenece
    .join('|'), 'g'),
  // use callback to replace with value in object
  function(m) {        
  // get value from object if exist or return the same if not found
    return result[m] || m;
  });

console.log(res);
```

```html
<p id="text">
  Hi [name], I really want to thank you. You([name]), really done a great job. user, [name]-[age]
</p>
```

---

Refer : [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)

Other method references :

1. [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
2. [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
3. [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
4. [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/join)

---

**UPDATE :** If patterns are the same then use a simple pattern match regex and replace using a callback function.

```js
var result = {
  '[name]': 'user_name',
  '[age]': 29
};

var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
res = text.replace(/\[\w+\]/g, function(m) {
  // get value from object if exist or return the same if not found
  return result[m] || m;
})

console.log(res);
```

```html
<p id="text">
  Hi [name], I really want to thank you. You([name]), really done a great job. user, [name]-[age]
</p>
```

Comment: I'd rather suggest to capture the pattern `[...]` and replace value in callback function

Comment: @Rajesh :  if the pattern is the same then that would be better.... I just added a generic solution...

Comment: Ya, i know... Its a tag (same pattern) level template parsing.
I also want the same..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex that captures your pattern and then use function that will fetch value from object.

```js
var str = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
var result = {
  '[name]': 'user_name',
  '[age]': 29
};
var reg = /(?:^|\[)(.*?)(?:}|\])/g
str = str.replace(reg, function(s) {
  // if key exists in object, replace its value, do not replace anything
  return result[s] || s;
})

console.log(str)
```

```html
<p id="text">
  Hi [name], I really want to thank you. You([name]), really done a great job. user, [name]-[age]. This is a [dummy] test case
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Or even more simply... This is an example for `[name]`, you would add string and value as necessary.

```
var text = document.getElementById('text').textContent;
text.replace(/\[name\]/g, 'Hello');
```

Answer (score -2):

To replace multiple times in JavaScript you can use `RegExp` replace.

```
var text = document.getElementByID('text');
var regex= new RegExp(string,'gmi'); // g: global, m: multiline, i: ignore case
text.replace(regex, value);
```