# How to use match javascript for search specific word?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use match javascript for search specific word ?

By this code I want to alert `not found`

```js
function check() {
  var str = "abcdefg";
  if (str.match(/abc/)) {
    alert("found");
  } else {
    alert("not found");
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="check()">CLICK HERE</div>
```

And for this code I want to alert `found`

```js
function check() {
  var str = "abc";
  if (str.match(/abc/)) {
    alert("found");
  } else {
    alert("not found");
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="check()">CLICK HERE</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try regex for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method for searching a match and  [use word boundary regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for exact  word match.

```html
<div onclick="check()">CLICK HERE</div>

<script>
  function check() {
    var str = "abcdefg";
    if (/\babc\b/.test(str)) {
      alert("found");
    } else {
      alert("not found");
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to generate regex from a string then use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor.

```html
<div onclick="check()">CLICK HERE</div>

<script>
  function check() {
    var str = "abcdefg",
      check = "abc";
    if (new RegExp('\\b' + check + '\\b').test(str)) {
      alert("found");
    } else {
      alert("not found");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Refer : [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)

Comment: @arectiyurokiyw then use `(new RegExp('\\b' + xx + '\\b')).test(str)`

Comment: @arectiyurokiyw Is here interview happening? The provided solutions doesn't work for you or what?