# Search multiple strings with indexOf() and add to Array

Tags: jquery

I have following working code.

```
indexMatches = [];
function getMatchIndexes(str, toMatch) {
    var toMatchLength = toMatch.length,
        match,
        i = 0;

    while ((match = str.indexOf(toMatch, i)) > -1) {
        indexMatches.push(toMatch);
        i = match + toMatchLength;
    }
    return indexMatches;
}

console.log(getMatchIndexes("this is code [table which has [table table [row and rows [table]", "[table"));
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vqqq1wj4/

However I have to match 2 string to search [table and [row and add to indexes. Currently it accepts only 1 parameter to search. I tried adding the same with OR operator in while but it doesnt work. Ideally I should write the following code

```
getMatchIndexes(str, "[table","[row");
```

and it would return the array below according to their index and positions properly.

```
 [ "[table", "[table", "[row", "[table" ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with regex which is generated using the string.

```js
function getMatchIndexes(str, ...toMatch) {
  return str.match(
    // generate regex
    new RegExp(
      // iterate over strings
      toMatch.map(function(v) {
        // escape symbols which has special meaning in regex
        return v.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&')
      // join with pipe operator and specify g for global match
      }).join('|'), 'g'));
}

console.log(getMatchIndexes("this is code [table which has [table table [row and rows [table]", "[table", "[row"));
```

---

Refer : [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)

Comment: Just for refernce, what does ... means ?

Comment: @Themer :  which is [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).. or pass the values as an array...... i.e, `console.log(getMatchIndexes("this is code [table which has [table table [row and rows [table]", ["[table", "[row"]]));` & `function getMatchIndexes(str, toMatch){....`

Comment: ok thanks. one last thing, if it now much as I never understand regex code. What if I search getMatchIndexes("this is code [table which has [table table [row and rows [table]", ["table", "row"]]); without [ bracket and it should ignore the word table but only count [table and return the same output..

Comment: @Themer : that would match `table`.... o/p => `[ "table", "table", "row", "table" ]`