# regex - efficiently capitalize all shortcuts from given list in a text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of shortcuts:

```
var shortcuts = ["efa","ame","ict","del","aps","lfb","bis","bbc"...
```

and a body of text of various capitalisation:

```
var myText = "Lorem ipsum... Efa, efa, EFA ...";
```

Is it possible to replace all the words in the text that match the shortcut list with a capitalised version of the shortcut using regex? Is it possible to do that without a loop only using **String.prototype.replace()**?

The desired outcome in my example would be:

```
myText = "Lorem ipsum... EFA, EFA, EFA ...";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate a single regex with the array of string and replace the string using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Syntax) method with a callback.

```js
var shortcuts = ["efa", "ame", "ict", "del", "aps", "lfb", "bis", "bbc"];

var myText = "Lorem ipsum... Efa, efa, EFA ...";

// construct the regex from the string
var regex = new RegExp(
  shortcuts
  // iterate over the array and escape any symbol
  // which has special meaning in regex, 
  // this is an optional part only need to use if string cotains any of such character
  .map(function(v) {
    // use word boundary in order to match exact word and to avoid substring within a word
    return '\\b' + v.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/g, '\\$&') + '\\b';
  })
  
  // or you can use word boundary commonly by grouping them
  // '\\b(?:' + shortcuts.map(...).join('|') + ')\\b'
  
  // join them using pipe symbol(or) although add global(g)
  // ignore case(i) modifiers
  .join('|'), 'gi');

console.log(
  // replace the string with capitalized text
  myText.replace(regex, function(m) {
    // capitalize the string
    return m.toUpperCase();
  })
  // or with ES6 arrow function
  // .replace(regex, m => m.toUpperCase())
);
```

---

Refer : [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek : added some explanation

Comment: You should add word boundaries around the shortcuts in the regex, otherwise this will transform words like "america" into "AMErica"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you control the initial shortcuts array and you know that it only contains characters:

```js
const shortcuts = ["efa","ame","ict","del","aps","lfb","bis","bbc"]

var text = "Lorem ipsum... Efa, efa, EFA, ame, America, enamel, name ..."

var regex = new RegExp("\\b(" + shortcuts.join('|') + ")\\b", 'gi')

console.log(text.replace(regex, s => s.toUpperCase()));
```

The `\b` boundaries will avoid replacing the shortcuts inside words.

Comment: you need to use `join('\\b|\\b')`

Comment: or `"\\b(" + shortcuts.join('|') + ")\\b"`

Comment: Now I am getting correct results. Thanks to both of you guys. In this instance I am using Jozef's shorter answer but @PranavCBalan described his solution which may help others so I am accepting his answer.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek : the shorter way is using arrow function, check its compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility .... If u don't want ES6 support then go with it

Comment: I am writing TypeScript so the arrow functions are fine

Answer (score 0):

a simple approach with no `join`:

```
var shortcuts = ["efa","ame","ict","del","aps","lfb","bis","bbc"], myText = "Lorem ipsum... Efa, efa, EFA ..aps apS whatever APS.";
shortcuts.map((el)=> {
myText = myText.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+el+'\\b',"gi"), el.toUpperCase())
});
console.log(myText);
```