# set regex with input variables

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I spent hours but can not fix my problem,

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var pattern = document.getElementById("inputpattern").value;
    var replacetext = document.getElementById("inputreplacetext").value;
    var n = str.replace(pattern,replacetext);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>
```

I need to set `str.replace(pattern,replacetext);` with html input fields, why doesn't it work?

Comment: How is this function getting invoked?

Comment: Look at this pls

Comment: https://codeshare.io/GbzlxM

Comment: @HassanImam and others pls

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression  Btw, var n = str.replace(eval(pattern),replacetext); will work, but you need to find some less evil way. ;)

Comment: @sinisake Thank you so much , just try to create a tool for some guys , then they can try regex in gui :) Thankss