# Replace all occurrences in file TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, replace

I need to replace all occurrences of a word for another in all txt files.
That works if I put like that:

```
const replace = require('replace-in-file');
const options = {
    files: './**/*.txt'
    from: /oneWord/g,
    to: 'anotherWord,

};
```

But, I need to use App' user input with process.argv[], and I could not find how to replace the

```
from: /oneWord/g,
```

for

```
from: '/'+ process.argv[3] + '/g'

const replace = require('replace-in-file');
var from = '/'+ process.argv[3] + '/g';
const options = {
files: process.argv[2],
from: process.argv[3],
to: process.argv[4],
```

Any help?

Comment: Here is link about how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression. 
And here is link to RegExp manual https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

In the options you must put your variable from instead of process.argv[3].