# JavaScript: Live filter using string or regex in form input tag

Tags: javascript, regex, filter

I have a single page on my local machine that I use a javascript live filter script that I got here:
https://css-tricks.com/in-page-filtered-search-with-vanilla-javascript/

It works very well for my needs but I would like to be able to use regex searches too.

At the moment I am trying...

```
function liveSearch() {
  // Locate the card elements
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards')
  // Locate the search input
  let search_query = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;

  let reg_query = /search_query/.test(cards[i].innerText)
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    // If the text is within the card...
    if (reg_query) {
      // ...remove the `.is-hidden` class.
      cards[i].classList.remove("is-hidden");
    } else {
      // Otherwise, add the class.
      cards[i].classList.add("is-hidden");
    }
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Eventually I would like to be able to filter using either a normal string or regex. Perhaps by prefixing a regex with something like '%:'.

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple problems with the code you've provided.

The first problem is that you're defining `reg_query` too early. It should be defined *within* the for loop. You could also define the expression itself, and test later, as I will demonstrate in a moment.

The second problem is that you're not actually using the variable `search_query` in your regular expression initialiser, and instead are creating a regex that matches the string - well - `search_query`.

Looking at the [MDN Docs for RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), you could try something along the lines of:

```js
// Match the word specifically...
let regex = RegExp(search_query);
// Or, match any text containing the term...
let regex = RegExp(`.*${search_query}.*`);
```

Here's an example to show you how this would work.

```js
// Some example values
const cards = ["value a", "value b", "item c", "object d", "another value e"]

const search_term = "value";
const search_exp = RegExp(`.*${search_term}.*`);
for(const card of cards) {
  if(search_exp.test(card)) {
    console.log(`Show: "${card}"`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Hide: "${card}"`);
  }
}
```